# Hospedar dois websites em um único VPS

Tags: apache

Estou tentando hospedar dois websites diferentes no mesmo VPS. Quais são os procedimentos corretos para se fazer isso?

O servidor `apache` já está instalado e eu consigo hospedar arquivos por lá. Porém não consigo hospedar dois sites diferentes.

Meu `httpd.conf` tem o seguinte:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin primeiro_site@primeiro_site.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/primeiro_site/public_html
     ServerName www.endereco1.com
     ServerAlias endereco1.com
     ErrorLog /var/www/primeiro_site/error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:800>
     ServerAdmin endereco2@endereco2.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/segundo_site/public_html
     ServerName www.endereco2.com
     ServerAlias endereco2.com
     ErrorLog /var/www/segundo_site/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Porém ambos os endereços redirecionam para a pasta do `site 1`...

Comment: Você colocou o `endereco2.com` na porta 800 de propósito?

Comment: Não entendo muito de servidores. Coloquei na 800 acreditando que eu poderia acessar da seguinte maneira 123.4.5.6:800 para o segundo site. Mas sem resultados satisfatórios...

Comment: Você restartou o `Apache` após fazer a mudança?

Comment: Eu sugiro que você deixe os dois na porta 80 para facilitar o acesso mas para testar você não pode se esquecer de configurar o `DNS` ou seu arquivo `hosts` para teste local.

Comment: Sim sim, várias e várias vezes. Segui os passos deste tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-6
A única coisa que não fiz foi justamente o "Optional Step Six—Setting Up the Local Hosts". Vou testar aqui se este seria o problema então.

Comment: O motivo de eu ter pulado este passo é que no tutorial eles dizem que se eu tiver redirecionado o meu dominio para o IP do VPS eu poderia pular aquele passo. E eu redirecionei ambos os endereços para o VPS. @Edit: Atualizei o código, e mudei ambos para a porta 80, ficando ambos com <VirtualHost *:80> Mas ainda sem resultados...

Comment: Eu normalmente faço de outro forma usando `sites-available` e `sites-enabled`. Quer que eu poste essa solução como uma resposta para você testar?

Comment: Claro, todas as soluções são bem vindas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro do diretório do `Apache` há um diretório chamado `sites-available`, nele há um exemplo chamado `000-default.conf`.

Para adicionar novos sites crie duas cópias desse arquivo: `010-site1.conf` e `020-site2.conf` (ou o nome que preferir) e dentro dele insira os Virtual Hosts.

### 010-site1.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin primeiro_site@primeiro_site.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/primeiro_site/public_html
     ServerName www.endereco1.com
     ServerAlias endereco1.com
     ErrorLog /var/www/primeiro_site/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

### 020-site2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin endereco2@endereco2.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/segundo_site/public_html
     ServerName www.endereco2.com
     ServerAlias endereco2.com
     ErrorLog /var/www/segundo_site/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Para ativar use a ferramenta `a2ensite`:

```
sudo a2ensite 010-site1.conf
sudo a2ensite 020-site1.conf
```

Ou simplesmente crie um **link simbólico** em `sites-enabled` para estes dois arquivos:

```
ln -s 010-site1.conf ../sites-enabled/010-site1.conf
ln -s 020-site2.conf ../sites-enabled/020-site2.conf
```

Para as mudanças serem aplicadas é necessário reiniciar o `Apache`

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: O diretório do Apache seria a pasta httpd certo? Se for, fui até ele e não existe essa pasta. Notei que você me sugeriu o comando para restartar o Apache usando "apache2", porém o VPS usa uma distribuição Red Hat do Linux (não sei se isso influência em algo, mas achei relevante citar) porém para restartar o apache eu uso "sudo /usr/sbin/httpd -k restart". Será que eu poderia criar essa pasta "sites-available" com mkdir?

Comment: Em algumas distros o `Apache2` chama `httpd`. Os diretórios devem ser `/etc/httpd/sites-available` e `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled` mas aparentemente você tem que adicionar uma linha `include ../sites-enabled` dentro de `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` então basta criar o link simbólico e recarregar usando `service httpd reload`.